# Magnetic field due to a line and a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I need to find the magnetic field produced by this arrangement

[image]

Let me explain the image: The vertical line is a conducting straight line with a current being conducted. Now, the horizontal line is actually a infinite plane, so the point of view of the image is like we were seeing horizontally. We need to find the field everywhere.

I am having problem to seek what curve i should chose to find the answer. I mean, it seems that the magnetic field above the plane is circularly symmetric around the field line. So that $B_{\phi} = \mu I / (2 \pi r)$. But what about the field due to the plane? Is it already included? I am rather confused

Comment: is the plane carrying current? is it simply a conducting plane?